# Powershell and trusted certificates

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to implement signed code for some PS scripts, and I have a question about trusting certificates.
I know the "right" way to address this is for IT to use Group Policy to trust the certificate office wide. But many of my customers just don't really have that option. My thought is to provide instructions on using CertUtil.exe to do the job, but I wanted to be 100% sure that adding to trustedpublisher this way still results in the certificate being validated by the issuing authority at startup or login, so a revoked certificate in trusted publishers would in fact not be trusted, correct?
Also, give that the tool to be run is a management tool, my initial thought is to use the tool to drive CertUtil.exe. Basically the first time you use it it adds its own certificate, so you get some user interaction required on first use only. But the idea of code creating a trust for itself seems potentially sketchy, and would raise a little flag for me if I was on the other side wearing my IT hat. So, from a PS distribution model standpoint, is setting up one's own certificate considered appropriate, or verboten, or something of a gray area?

Comment: 1. Revoked cert is not considered 'OK'.

Comment: When/how often does a "trusted" cert get checked for revocation? At every startup/logon? Periodically during use? I have seen Architects leave the computers on, logged in and running software for (I kid you not) months at a time. I want to reassure my IT folks that even under those circumstances the certificate gets regular validation and remains "safe". Any MS white paper on the topic would probably be good thing to point them at as a trusted third party. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly revocation is almost immediate, with a possible short time lag due to pre-fetching.  you can find more info on how exactly revocation is handled here - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619754(v=ws.10).aspx

As far as adding your own cert I don't see an issue with it but if they require code signing for scripts it won't be able to do it's initial launch, personally I'd send the certutil stuff as a separate script (potentially a batch file) and keep the code you are actually sending over all signed.

Comment: Mike, the script will be delivered signed. The key is that it is used for ongoing maintenance, so my goal is to have the initial use throw a warning, but then the code will add the cert so that all subsequent uses will happen without the warning, assuming the cert remains valid. That said, it looks like just changing the shortcut to AllSigned will allow the user to choose Always Run, which then adds the cert, assuming the user is a local admin. That may be all I need, which would be great. And, thanks for the link. I do want to be able to send folks to good resources, if for transparency only.